# IntelliJ is unable to import hamcrest library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, hamcrest

I'm having some trouble importing my project from **build.gradle** file.
It's not able to find classes from **hamcrest-core-1.3.jar**.

```
gradle clean build
```

runs successfully on terminal.

My environment is

```
Intellij 2016.3.1
Gradle 2.14.1
```

It was able to resolve the reference one time but it went away on restart. When it was able to resolve hamcrest, it later failed to resolve pigunit jar. I got **NoSuchMethodError** (class was loaded from wrong jar) also once.

**Invalidate Cache** also didn't work.
I tried importing the project from scratch multiple times.
Please let me know if any other information is needed.

For some reason *org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers* loads CoreMatchers from 
**mockito-all-1.10.19.jar** instead of **hamcrest-core-1.3.jar**.I played around with the order of these two jars in the modules libraries.

Please refer to the screenshot below.
[image: Snapshots]

Comment: maybe it's an issue with dependecies order. Just import mockito-core instead of mockito-all (which is bundle with hamcrest)

Comment: In your build.gradle file make sure the hamcrest entry comes before mockito entry.

Comment: if there's any problem with build.gradle, then `gradle clean build` should fail, right?

Comment: Got it working after rearranging the dependencies in **Project Settings**